# How to identify check box using their parent labels in JAVA Swings

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel that has different sections and each section has a set of checkboxes.

My Panel Looks like

Section 1
Checkbox A
Checkbox B

Section 2
Checkbox B
Checkbox C

Section 3
Checkbox A
Checkbox c

Is there a way to identify when a checkbox A is selected, it is from section 1 or section 3.

Comment: No, you can't add the same component twice to a container. Checkbox A cannot exist in both section 1 and 3. Maybe put in a little more effort into explaining your problem, and showing some code attempts, _then_ maybe we can offer some alternatives, it we understand the requirement better

Comment: As @peeskillet said, the situation you described is impossible, so probably you should add some additional info (maybe source code or screenshot)